# Parsing HTML table using Jsoup Scala

Tags: java, html, scala, parsing, jsoup

I would like to extract the Deck Name, that is "Jund" from the table below. I am using Jsoup for the purpose. I am already able to extract the required table using the class in which the table contains but I am not able to extract the deck name.

```
<table style="width:100%;padding:35px;" class="table_deck"> 
 <tbody>
  <tr> 
   <th style="width:66%;" align="left" colspan="2"> Reid Duke playing Jund </th> 
   <th scope="position"> Position: 18 </th> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <th style="width:66%;" align="left" colspan="2"> Deck Name: Jund </th> 
   <th scope="hide"> Sideboard </th> 
  </tr> 

 </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using following code to get the required table present in desired class. I am new to scala and your help would be great for me.

```
val jsoup = Jsoup.parse(content)
val table = jsoup.select("table[class=table_deck]").first()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pseudo selector contains: `Jsoup.parse(html).select("th:contains(Deck Name)").text()`

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax